# How can I avoid repetition in python/kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to make an app that have many functions associate to one buttons each. This way, if I have 70 buttons I have 70 different functions. I want to add, the respective value, when I click respective button, to a respective variable label (I am using numericproperty). As the change between this functions is only in this numeric value, I would like to make this in a more inteligent way than I did. Have anybody one suggestion of better way to do it without I have to repeat my code? Very thanks everybody, and part of my code is bellow.

.py

```
class SegundoScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'dois'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def mucarela(self, *args):
        screen4 = self.manager.get_screen('carrinho')
        screen4.btn1 = BubbleButton(text="Muçarela", font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None), background_normal='1.png', background_down='2.png')
        screen4.lb1 = Label(text="25,00", font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None))
        screen4.ids.lb5.value += 25
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.btn1)
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.lb1)

    def catupiry(self, *args):
        screen4 = self.manager.get_screen('carrinho')
        screen4.btn2 = BubbleButton(text="Catupiry",font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None), background_normal='2.png', background_down='1.png')
        screen4.lb2 = Label(text="25,00",font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None))
        screen4.ids.lb5.value += 25
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.btn2)
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.lb2)

    def peru(self, *args):
        screen4 = self.manager.get_screen('carrinho')
        screen4.btn2 = BubbleButton(text="Peito de peru",font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None), background_normal='1.png', background_down='2.png')
        screen4.lb2 = Label(text="95,00",font_size='20dp', size_hint=(1,None))
        screen4.ids.lb5.value += 35
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.btn2)
        screen4.ids.grid.add_widget(screen4.lb2)
```

[...]

and .kv

```
StackLayout:
    orientation: 'tb-lr'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, .9)
        pos_hint:{'x': .0, 'y': .0}
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 45, 50
            spacing: 25, 50
            size_hint: (1, 1)
            size_hint_y:  None
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: 500
            Label:
                text: "[b]Escolha[/b]\n[i]Sabor[/i]"
                markup: True
                font_size: '20dp'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Label:
                text: "[b]Preço\n[/b] [i](R$)[/i]"
                markup: True
                font_size: '20dp'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

        Button:
            text: "[b]Muçarela[/b]\n[i]Muçarela, tomate\n e orégano[/i]"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            background_normal:'1.png'
            background_down:'2.png' 
            on_press: root.mucarela()

        Label:
            text: "25,00"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Button:
            text: "[b]Catupiry[/b]\n[i]Catupiry, azeitona\n e tomate[/i]"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            background_normal:'2.png'
            background_down:'1.png'
            on_press: root.catupiry()

        Label:
            text: "25,00"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Button:
            text: "[b]Peito de peru[/b]\n[i]Muçarela, peito de peru\n e tomate[/i]"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            background_normal:'1.png'
            background_down:'2.png'
            on_press: root.peru()

        Label:
            text: "35,00"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Button:
            text: "[b]Portuguesa[/b]\n[i]Muçarela, presunto,\n cebola e ovo[/i]"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            background_normal:'2.png'
            background_down:'1.png'
            on_press: root.portuguesa()

        Label:
            text: "27,00"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Button:
            text: "[b]Toscana[/b]\n[i]Calabresa moída, muçarela\ne parmesão[/i]"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            background_normal:'1.png'
            background_down:'2.png'
            on_press: root.toscana()

        Label:
            text: "35,00"
            markup: True
            font_size: '20dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

and I have more one class form that is just one label numericpropertie whose change the value when respective button has clicked. As the change is only in this label, I am locking for how can I take the price value from the text label, and flavor name from the text button. Very thanks.

Comment: This question might be better for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it's a working script.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have so much experience with stackoverflow. Can I ask it in there? I just know it.

Comment: [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about *"Improve code that you wrote or maintain"*, and Stack Overflow is for questions about programming and not as much about reviewing code. You might get an answer here as well but Code review is made for these kinds of questions.

Comment: very thanks man, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

for your .kv file I recommend using Classes like

```
<MyButton@Button>:
        markup: True
        font_size: '20dp'
        size_hint_y: None
```

then in your code you could use instances of MyButton which could minify your code a little bit.